# persist variable between gnu parallel processes

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I have a simple script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

count=0

while read -A words
do
    # set count for processed records
    ((count++))
    printf ":%d:\n" $count
    ..
    ..
    ..

    # go find something in somefile
    grep "$regex" somefile
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "NOTHING" # check if we found any
    echo "--------------------------------"
done
```

Then I use `gnu parallel` to run it in multiple threads:

```
time head -2 fileA | parallel --bar -k -j 4 "echo {} | ./myscript.sh" > result
```

And all works well except that my `count` variable always has a value of 1, and
I would like it to increment on each read line as it was before I started to
use `gnu parallel`..

Here is a sample output:

```
:1:  # is one
Num of words: (3)
acrylic, plastic, sheets
NOTHING
--------------------------------
:1:  # should be 2 here
Num of words: (2)
act, creators
NOTHING
--------------------------------
```

How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel has {#} which is the job number. You can probably use that:

```
myfunc() {
  echo Looking at line number "$1"
  echo Input on stdin is:
  cat
}
export -f myfunc

cat /usr/share/dict/words | parallel -k --pipe -N1 myfunc {#}
```